# Regular expression to find text between characters from specific location

Tags: c#, hl7

Can someone please help me write an expression to get a value between 5th and 6th pipe of OBX segment (bold text below):

OBX|1|ST|PDF^Display Format in PDF^BASE64|26|JVBERi0xLjMNCiXS50K||||||P

Comment: Did you even try *anything*? SO is not ment to be a code-service.

Comment: Why not go for split and get the nth item in the string array? Regex is not the best choice for all string parsing

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle that did it

Answer (score 1):

```
// split by pipe
string[] strArray = text.Split('|');
// taking sixth element in resulting array
string value = strArray[5].ToString();
```